# What is the proper scope to use in IAMCredentialsClient for a GCP cloud function 2nd gen that requires authentication from a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, service-accounts, google-iam, google-identity

I have this code to generate an access token for a GCP Cloud Function 2nd gen:

```
const {IAMCredentialsClient} = require('@google-cloud/iam-credentials');

// Creates a client
const client = new IAMCredentialsClient();

async function generateAccessToken() {
    const [token] = await client.generateAccessToken({
        name: `projects/-/serviceAccounts/<MY SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>@<MY PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`,
        scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
    });
    console.info(token);
}
generateAccessToken();
```

But it gives me a 401 error when I use the token that it logs in Postman. I'm assuming that I'm not using the right scope/scopes.

What is the correct scope/scopes? Or am I making a different mistake? This code DOES produce a token, the token just doesn't run the function.

Comment: In that case, you impersonate a service account. You should not have the permission to do that. Have a look in the comment of the sample code here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/iam-credentials/latest#using-the-client-library

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere This allowed me to create a token but the token still gave me a 401 Error when I used it in postman. This is my example code https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/ef1d487bb0b3d936f27428157f97cb11 . Also in order for a token to be created I still had to provide my credentials with `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...`

Comment: You have a 401 in the subsequent request? or to generate the token?

Comment: I have a 401 in the subsequent request (when I try to use my token in Postman to call the cloud function). I am able to generate the token just fine

Comment: Ok, so I guess your service account that you just impersonated does not have the permission to perform the operation. 401 mean unauthorized

Comment: But it does permission, when I run this code https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/e250cdda91f5a2521b23188d78c84326. and my service account is in `CREDENTIALS_STR`. It works

Comment: I'm sorry I was never able to resolve this.

Comment: To create, update, or perform other administrative actions on a function, you must have a principal that has an appropriate role. Check [Authenticating function to function calls](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create, update, or perform other administrative actions on a function, you must have a principal that has an appropriate role. Check [Authenticating function to function calls](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls) for more information.

Create a service account with no permissions except to invoke your Cloud Function, deploy the JSON key for that account with your calling code, and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

If the code generates an access token for a GCP Cloud Function 2nd gen, If it  supports Oauth-2, Try to use [Google's Workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) for more information.